# Back Button Using pushState + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url like /search/mySearch

I have implemented infinite scrolling which working 100% fine but issue is 
when i click on any link than new pages open, now when i click on system back i want my cursor to be at same exact point but it behaves randomly.
Please Help.

below my code

```
url: '/search/perform?photo=Y',
type: 'GET', 
data: globalSRParams,
success: function(response) {
    globalSRParams= response.pageNo + 1;
    history.pushState({}, "title that make sense" + page_index1, 'mySearch/?page=' + page_index1);
```

Comment: `i want my cursor to be at same exact point but it behaves randomly` What does this mean?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it coming in the place where i 1st set the pushState